# Xamarin Forms and Azure AD B2C login issues

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to figure out how to use Azure AD B2C with Xamarin Forms.  All the examples and documentation from Microsoft has said do no use this in production for the last year.   Even a blog post from last week says this.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/

What other options do we have?

Comment: Have you excluded Visual Studio Mobile Center's Identity/Auth capabilities? I know it also is currently a work-in-progress, but maybe it would another option to consider. It is disappointing to see that B2C is still incomplete for this scenario, as it's been GA for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

As you've indicated, MSAL is in preview and therefore not production ready. Work is ongoing to get MSAL to a production support level. I would recommend that you vote for this ask in the Azure AD B2C forum to support it and get updates on its progress: [Production support for MSAL](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18909109-production-support-for-msal)

Given that, at this point your options are:

- Wait for MSAL production support.
- Find and use a third party Xamarin OpenID Connect library.
- Code down to the protocol yourself.

---

**UPDATE: MSAL is now supported in production.** [Read this blog post for more info](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/start-writing-applications-today-with-the-new-microsoft-authentication-sdks/)